# Undefined is not an object when using react-native-form-generator

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error when trying to set up a simple form in with react-native-form-generator:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react3.default.PropTypes.string')
```

I am thinking it is some kind of dependency issue with react-native-form-generator, but looking at its docs example doesn't lead me to believe I haven't imported anything necessary.  Googling the error message made me think I just needed to include the PropTypes library, but I tried that and no luck.

Checking this issue: https://github.com/MichaelCereda/react-native-form-generator/issues/123

says they fixed this problem 3 days ago, and I just installed the library today.  I figure I will just show my code on here and see if anyone has any ideas, and look for a new form library.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, InputField, Seperator } from 'react-native-form-generator';
import { Button } from 'react-navigation';
//import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

var FormHolder = <Form 
            ref="signInForm" 
            onChange={this.handleFormChange.bind(this)}
            label="Sign In">
              <Seperator/>
              <InputField
                ref="email"
                label="Email"
              />
              <InputField
                ref="password"
                label="Password"
              />

              // <Button title="Log In" />

            </Form>


class LogInForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      formData: {}
    }
  }

  handleFormChange(formData){


    this.setState({formData:formData});
    this.props.onFormChange && this.props.onFormChange(formData);
  }


  render(){
    return (FormHolder);
  }
}


export default LogInForm
```

I am using React 16.0.0 and react-native 0.50.3

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `react-native-form-generator` didn't update to fix this prop-types issue so you'll need to correct it by replacing all propTypes import in js files of this module like [someone did in this PR](https://github.com/MichaelCereda/react-native-form-generator/pull/124/files)